# Azure DevOps: Nuget.config is not valid

Tags: .net, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, nuget-package-restore

My pipeline is encounter an error that I just dont know how to fix.As you can see below, a selected and custom nuget feed is used. The solution works fine locally with all nuget dependecies.

The error that I encounter:

```
 C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\6.0.407\NuGet.targets(649,5): error : NuGet.Config is not valid XML. Path: 'D:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_325.config'. [D:\a\1\s\Helpers\Helpers.csproj]
 C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\6.0.407\NuGet.targets(649,5): error :   The '$' character, hexadecimal value 0x24, cannot be included in a name. Line 1, position 273. [D:\a\1\s\Helpers\Helpers.csproj]
```

My YAML where it fails:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
        feedsToUse: 'select'
        vstsFeed: $(vstsFeed)
```

**UPDATE**:
I removed variable $(vstsFeed) and replaced it with the actual value which helped, that variable itself is stored in DevOps Library.

**UPDATE**:
I noticed that I had not define the variable group in my yaml and therefore the value could not be read. Working example below, the dotnet restore part is in a file called builder.yml.

```
- stage: Build
    displayName: Build and create artifacts
    jobs:
      - job: "Build"
        timeoutInMinutes: ${{variables.pipelineTimeout}}
        variables:
          - group: "Common_shared"
        pool:
          vmImage: ${{variables.vmImage}}
        steps:
          - template: "builder.yml"
```

Comment: In your Helpers.csproj file on line 1, position 273, is there any chance that there's a dollar sign character?  What does that line look like?

Comment: There is no dollar sign appearing in my Helpers.csproj file.
It starts with :
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">